# std::forward and factory that calls std::make_shared

Tags: c++11, forward, make-shared

I have code like this...

```
X* raw = ::new X("abc");
// do something benign to object
std::shared_ptr<X> ptr(raw);
```

Now consider the same using an object factory...

```
template<typename T, typename... A>
std::shared_ptr<T> factory(A&&... args) {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<A>(args)...);
    // do something benign to object
    return ptr;
}

std::shared_ptr<X> ptr = factory<X>("abc");
```

This is a simplified example, but I'm seeing an unexplained crash when using the factory that appears to be due to a corrupted shared pointer.

I'm not familiar with the innards of `std::make_shared`, but am wondering if it in turn does something like argument forwarding to placement `::new`, and that this chain forwarding is a problem.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me, including the forwarding. Can you provide a stack trace of the crash? You might want to try to run it with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: When you `make_shared`, the object and the reference counting and the like are located right next to each other.  When you allocate then wrap a shared ptr around it, they exist far away.  If you are corrpting memory right before your object, in the `make_shared` case you'll be corrupting the shared ptr booking data...

Comment: Retracting the question.  Something in the "benign" process was actually not.